# Is it necessary to use .str() for storing match.suffix() in regex_search?

Tags: c++, regex, string

I have to use the suffix of the match result for regex_search. The string that I have is approx million lines and its taking on an average of 30ms for just assigning it to a temp string.
If I don't use .str(), even then the program is working fine and it takes on an average the same 30ms. Using the time reference just for comparison purpose.

```
regex_search(input, match, re);
tempStr = match.suffix().str();
```

Kindly let me know the purpose of .str() if there is no significant difference in the time(milliseconds).

Comment: Please post your compilation flags you used to build the program.  If you're timing an unoptimized or "debug" build, the timings you're showing are meaningless.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am using visual studio and I am sorry I don't know how to set compilation flags in this. Ignoring the timing, could you please tell me the use of .str() ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you timing a "Release" build or a "Debug" build?  If it is a "Debug" build, then stop what you're doing and build a release version and time that.

Comment: Does that have any effect in the use of .str() is what you mean or million lines wouldn't take 30ms in release build?

Comment: Please run a release build.  The question is worthless until you do so.  That is the point I'm making.  There are many questions on SO, where the questions asks "why is doing x slow?", and it turns out that the person asking the question was running an unoptimized build.  Once the optimized build was run, the timings were then "corrected", and thus the question closed, deleted, etc.

Comment: I totally understand what you are trying to say. I missed to another point. For a 1000 lines input, it takes 0ms and for million lines it took 30ms. And the main doubt is about str() and not the time taken by suffix(). I took the reference of time just to compare that there is no significant difference in time if .str() added or removed and hence what is the use of it.

Comment: The compiler can optimize code away.  That's the point.  The first thing you should do is write code that is understandable as-is, using `str()`, `suffix()`, whatever is understandable to you and other programmers.  If you ran an optimized build, and found it it took 5ms and not 30ms, or even the same 0ms, that renders the question rather meaningless or close to meaningless.  That's why all questions regarding timing issues w.r.t C++ should accompany with those timings, the build/compiler settings used to build the application.

Comment: Thanks and now could you please answer question that I have asked? What is the use of .str(), Is it necessary to be used along with match.suffix()?

Comment: Please note how SO works.  The comment section is for comments, so I am commenting on your code and the details in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it necessary to use .str() for storing match.suffix() in regex_search?

No. `match.suffix()` is implicitly convertible to `string`, and the effect is equivalent to calling `.str()`.

I guess explicitly calling `.str()` is only needed in presence of type deduction:

```
auto match(std::regex re, std::string s) {
    std::smatch m;
    std::regex_match(s, m, re);
    // return m.suffix(); // bad: the return value is dangling
    return m.suffix().str(); // OK: copies the matched part
}
```